# Is it possible for make application only compatible with 64-bit, not with 32-bit architecture

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I'm working on windows applications. I've created a application for windows(64-bit). But when I have installed that application on my system. In services, it is showing **something.exe * 32**. But I want to make that application only compatible with 64-bit windows, not with 32-bit. 
Q1. Is it possible for make application only compatible with 64-bit, not with 32-bit architecture?
Q2. if it is possible, then please tell me the factors which make it 64-bit compatible only, not 32-bit.
Q3. What changes i need to make for compatibility with 64-bit Windows only.

Comment: ya it is created when i install and run my application.. But I want to make application which will be shown like **something.exe** (without *32) in services and I have my application in Java

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed the 64-bit Java runtime, or for some reason are launching the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Compile it using 64-bit op codes and 64 bit registers and it will not run on a 32 bit Windows system.  For example, using GCC, you can add the `-arch x86_64` option to force 64 bit compilation.

You, however, have not stated which language you're using.  If you're using Java or some other byte-code style language then there's nothing that you can do.

Comment: I'm working on a application which is written in Java. So, there is any chance/method to make it compatible only with **64-bit**.

Comment: I would say no to that.  Whatever you write is compiled into java byte code which is interpreted by the JVM.  There is no such thing as writing 64 bit Java code.

Comment: But i have seen some applications (third Party software, **not remember the name**) which are written in Java and have compatibility with 64-bit arch. Windows only.
Because we will made **.jar** from the java byte code and then make a **installer** (.exe or msi) of that using Tools. So is their any tool which help in making the same?